# Create discrepancy between size on disk and actual size in NTFS

Tags: ntfs

I keep finding files which show a size of 10kb but a size on disk on 10gb.  Trying to figure out how this is done, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You can make sparse files on NTFS, as well as on any real filesystem. :-)

Seek to (10 GB - 10 kB), write 10 kB of data. There, you have a so-called 10 GB file, which in reality is only 10 kB big. :-)

Comment: @unixman83: The OP's account has been nuked long ago (see how his name is greyed out). It's not possible for any answer to this question to be accepted. :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can create streams in NTFS files.  It's like a separate file, but with the same filename.  See here: [Alternate Data Streams](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Alternate_Data_Streams.html)

Comment: ADSs can be used to hide all kinds of "lovely stuff". :-) I look at them rather like resource forks (using a MacOS analogy); in fact, in the MS implementation of Apple file sharing, ADSs are indeed used to hold resource forks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your case (or it might be a mistake in your question) but when you create a NTFS sparse file it will show different sizes for these fields.

When I create a 10MB sparse file and fill it with 1MB of data windows explorer will show:
  
  
  Size: 10MB
  
  Size on disk: 1MB

But in your case its the opposite. (or a mistake.)